# How can I use block elements (░ ▒ ▓ █) in Overleaf?

Tags: fonts, overleaf

I want to use [block elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements) (░ ▒ ▓ █) in a document I am creating in Overleaf.

According to Wikipedia:

> Font sets like Code2000 and the DejaVu family—include coverage for each of the glyphs in the Block Elements range, Unifont also contains all the glyphs. Among the fonts in widespread use, full implementation is provided by Segoe UI Symbol.

I found DejaVu in the [font catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/dejavusans/). I tried using this but the block elements do not show.

```
\usepackage{DejaVuSans}
%% Another possibility is
%% \usepackage{dejavu}
%% which loads the DejaVu Serif and DejaVu Sans Mono fonts as well
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

What alternatives are there?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{DejaVuSans}
%% Another possibility is
%% \usepackage{dejavu}
%% which loads the DejaVu Serif and DejaVu Sans Mono fonts as well
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} %% Only if the base font of the document is to be sans serif
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

░ ▒ ▓ █

\end{document}
```

Comment: if you use T1 encoding the font only has 256 characters fully taken up with latin alphabetic characters. You could use the original Unicode OpenType fonts with lualatex.

Comment: As David suggested, I think this is a font package/encoding limitation rather than anything specific to Overleaf (I'm on support staff at Overleaf). If you use the OpenType fonts and LuaLaTeX as suggested, things seem to work OK on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/zttqryjbwbqr

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to Latex. The document where I want to use this in the end is complied with XeLaTeX (I am using a template and have been told to compile with XeLaTeX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works in LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. (not using Overleaf).  The use of `fontspec` in lieu of `T1` encoding allows the full unicode font set provided by the font to be accessed directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVuSans}
\begin{document}

░ ▒ ▓ █ X

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works, but how can I use it in a document with another font (set in the same way that you provided)? I guess the question is, how can I restrict the font to the instances where I want the blocks. If I put both `\setmainfont{font1}` and `\setmainfont{DejaVuSans}` in the preamble, only the last one is effective.

Comment: @user249053 use `\newfontfamily\djvs{DejaVuSans} ` instead of `\setmainfont` then use `\djvs` to select the font where needed